# How to make all the rows of a Dataset appear?

Tags: dataset, elements

Impossible to solve the hereunder question:

How to make the 4 rows of "governing" to appear instead of only the 2 first one and a gray line saying "4 total >"?

```
Dataset[
 {
  Association[
   "Workflow" ->
    Association[
     
     "modeling" ->
      Association[
       "binarizing" -> binarizing,
       "quantifying" -> quantifying
       ],
     
     "simulating" ->
      Association[
       "decomposing" -> decomposing,
       "transforming" -> transforming
       ],
     
     "governing" ->
      Association[
       "testing" -> testing,
       "observing" -> observing,
       "controling" -> controling,
       "solving" -> solving
       
       ]
     ]
   ]},
 ItemSize -> {Automatic}
 ]
```

Comment: Due to the nesting, there are more levels than just rows and columns. Use the option `MaxItems -> {All, All, All, All}`

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2451024).

Answer (score 3):

```
Dataset[{Association[
   "Workflow" -> 
    Association[
     "modeling" -> 
      Association["binarizing" -> binarizing, 
       "quantifying" -> quantifying], 
     "simulating" -> 
      Association["decomposing" -> decomposing, 
       "transforming" -> transforming], 
     "governing" -> 
      Association["testing" -> testing, "observing" -> observing, 
       "controling" -> controling, "solving" -> solving]]]}, 
 ItemSize -> {Automatic}, MaxItems -> {4, 4, 4, 4}]
```

[image]

Comment: Superb, Daniel. Thanks a lot for you prompt solution which was not evident to myself. Regards. Gianni